# When object is created in this program?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.io.*;
class obj
{
  obj()
  {
    System.out.println("This method in the class");
  }
  String meth()
  {
    return "Aint Defined";
  }
}

class obj1 extends obj
{
  void calll()
  {
    System.out.println(super.meth());
  }
}

class obj2
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    obj1 o1=new obj1();
    o1.calll();
  }
}
```

When does the object is created for the class obj in this program.
 Is it when the run time reaches this code

```
class obj1 extends obj
```

or is it when run time reaches this code inside println

```
super.meth()
```

Comment: The "runtime" does not reach the first one, it is not a statement.

Comment: What do you think? Can you execute the code and see when are you getting "This method in the class.." gets printed? Don't you think at the point where you can say super.meth(), super must already be there?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth . yeah okay. So is it created when it reaches the second code.? Is my question right.?

Comment: @prabugp . yeah i get the output bro . But my doubt is there should be an object created for the class obj isn't it. Does the super keyword creates object for that .? thats my question .?

Comment: @user3414734: Just to be really clear: *"When does the object is created for the class obj in this program."* No object of class `obj` is ever created by the above. An object of class `obj1` is created. That object has features it gets from the class `obj`, but it's an `obj1`, not an `obj`. That's not very clear from the answer you've accepted, [kasi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23442086/157247) is clearer about that, so I wanted to emphasize it for you.

Comment: @user3414734: The standard format for class names is to start them with an initial upper case letter, e.g. `Obj`, `Obj1`, and `Obj2`, not `obj`, `obj1`, and `obj2`. Not following that standard makes it ***very*** hard for people to read your code, strongly recommend following it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is created with the "new" keyword.

So in this case

```
obj1 o1=new obj1(); //creates obj1 (including its parent, obj)
```

Comment: oh okay .. that's what i expected . got it cleared now.

Answer (score 2):

You do not create object of class `obj` in your program. The sequence is:

- `obj1` instance is created
- `obj1` method `calll()` is called

  - Inside inherited method `meth()` is called (I think `super` is not needed in this example)
- Program ends

More to sequence when object is created:
[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.5)

Comment: yeah i know . but i'm just trying to understand whats going on behind the code.

Answer (score 1):

`o1` is created when the runtime executes `obj1 o1=new obj1();`

Answer (score 1):

The object is created when the statement `obj1 o1 = new obj1();` is executed. It seems you are also concerned about the order of execution of constructors when inheritance is involed. [This link](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Always Runtime starts execution from the main method.

so your execution starts from main and inside main method you have below lines

```
 obj1 o1=new obj1();
    o1.calll();
```

and objects are always created when we use new followed by one of the constrcutor
of the class.

so in your case `new obj1();` creates an object in the heap when the runtime reaches this line and before creating it calls the constrcutor obj1();

after creating o1 variable will be pointing to that new object created.

using o1 you can access the state of the object(methods and vaiables)